# PlatformException(ad_not_loaded, show failed for rewarded video, no ad was loaded, null) in flutter app

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I'm trying to show reward video ads in my flutter app.
Sometimes it works perfectly fine and some other times I get this error "PlatformException(ad_not_loaded, show failed for rewarded video, no ad was loaded, null)"

Here is how I load and show ads:

```
  MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: ['6E85178A5E7B957403B497917D014D74'],
  );
  try {
      await RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(
          adUnitId:getRewardBasedVideoAdUnitId(), targetingInfo: targetingInfo);

      await RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: AppStrings.adFailed,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
      );
    }
```

Usually this happens when ad hows successfully then the next time it fails and the time after it succeeds and so on, Maybe I need to reset something after ad shows successfully?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda coming late but I hope it helps someone out there.

The above condition usually happens because the `load` function returns before actually loading the ad.

**This answer is a hack rather than a solution.**

after initializing the plugin;

checkout the code below

```
showRewardAd() async {

  RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(
     adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
     targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  );

  bool _adIsDisplayed = false;
  do {
    try {
      _adIsDisplayed = (await RewardedVideoAd.instance.show() ?? false);
    } catch (e) {}
  } while (!_adIsDisplayed);
 }
}
```

calling `showRewardAd` will forcefully show an ad. do not forget to add a loader to indicate progress while the ad loads.

we can leverage the fact that the `show()` methods of the `RewardedVideoAd` instance returns a `Future<true>` when successful and `Future<false>` otherwise.

using a do while loop will keep it trying to show the ad, till it succeeds, without throwing any error...

This may not be a wanted behavior so you might want to throw an error at some point during the loop, say after 5 - 10 tries, so we don't have an infinite loop.